# how to correctly export a complex function from one js file to another js file

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, module, es6-modules

i have this code, i'm trying to export it to another js file, and i can calmly say i have zero idea how to do it. here is the code below. I would like to execute this time function in another JavaScript file. So far i have tried so many forms but to no avail, any suggestions is appreciated. Thanks.

```
function my_Clock() 
{
  this.cur_date = new Date();
   this.hours = this.cur_date.getHours();
  this.minutes = this.cur_date.getMinutes();
  this.seconds = this.cur_date.getSeconds();
}
my_Clock.prototype.run = function ()
{
  setInterval(this.update.bind(this), 1000);
};
my_Clock.prototype.update = function () 
{
  this.updateTime(1);
  console.log(this.hours + ":" + this.minutes + ":" + this.seconds);
 };
my_Clock.prototype.updateTime = function (secs) 
{
  this.seconds+= secs;
  if (this.seconds >= 60)
  {
    this.minutes++;
    this.seconds= 0;
  }
  if (this.minutes >= 60)
  {
    this.hours++;
    this.minutes=0;
  }
  if (this.hours >= 24)
  {
    this.hours = 0;
  }
};
var clock = new my_Clock();
 clock.run();
```

i have done this:

```
module.exports = {
my_Clock: function () {
    this.cur_date = new Date();
    this.hours = this.cur_date.getHours();
    this.minutes = this.cur_date.getMinutes();
    this.seconds = this.cur_date.getSeconds();
  }
}
 module.exports= {
   my_Clock: function () {
       my_Clock.prototype.run = function () {
           setInterval(this.update.bind(this), 1000);
        }
    }
 }

module.exports= {
   my_Clock: function () {
      my_Clock.prototype.update = function () {
          this.updateTime(1);
          return this.hours + "-" + this.minutes + "-" + this.seconds;
      }
  }
}


module.exports= {
  my_Clock: function () {
    my_Clock.prototype.updateTime = function (secs) {
        this.seconds += secs;
        if (this.seconds >= 60) {
            this.minutes++;
            this.seconds = 0;
        }
        if (this.minutes >= 60) {
            this.hours++;
            this.minutes = 0;
        }
        if (this.hours >= 24) {
            this.hours = 0;
           }
       }
     }
 }
```

i am trying to execute it like this in another file

```
const myModule = require('../functions/timefunction');
var clock = new myModule.my_Clock().my_Clock();
clock.run();
```

Please anybody help!!!!!

Comment: Given that your `my_Clock` works as expected (the first code block in the post), have you simply tried to say `module.exports = my_Clock;` and then `const my_Clock = require(pathToThatFile); const clock = new myClock();`?

Comment: You sir are a genius, that was so quick, wowsers. it works, one more thing, i used console.log to ouput the time, i have been trying to use return to return a sting but it keeps returning "undefined", any idea kind sir

Comment: Thank you very much @SamiHult, i finally got it working i had to use call backs interesting.